# Command writing to standard error does not produce output to ccnet project report?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I wrote a small c program like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

void main()
{
  fputs("test\r\n", stderr);
  fflush(stderr);
  ExitProcess(-1);
}
```

and included it like this in ccnet.config:

```
<project name="foobar">
  <tasks>
    <exec>
     <executable>C:\temp\test.exe</executable>
    </exec>
  </tasks>
</project>
```

When I forced the foobar project, I got not output whatsoever in the project report.

Why?

I may also mention that if I deliberately misspell the exe-filename, I get an exception (which I appreciate).

Edit:
When debugging CruiseControl.NET, writing a test that tries to run the exe file
that looks like this

```
[Test]
public void FooTest()
{
    const string xml = "<exec executable=\"C:\\temp\\test.exe\"><buildArgs></buildArgs></exec>";

    task = (ExecutableTask) NetReflector.Read(xml);

    var result = (IntegrationResult) IntegrationResult();
    result.Label = "1.0";
    result.BuildCondition = BuildCondition.ForceBuild;
    result.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\temp\";
    result.ArtifactDirectory = @"c:\temp\";

    task.Run(result);

    Assert.AreEqual(IntegrationStatus.Failure, result.Status);

    Assert.IsFalse(task.WasSuccessful);
    var firstTaskResult = (ProcessTaskResult)result.TaskResults[0];
    Debug.WriteLine(firstTaskResult.Data);
}
```

The debug console will output xml like this:

```
<buildresults>
    <task>
        <buildArgs />
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
        <baseDirectory />
        <dynamicValues />
        <environment />
        <executable>C:\temp\test.exe</executable>
        <priority>Normal</priority>
        <successExitCodes />
    </task>
    <message level="Error">test</message>
</buildresults>
```

(note, I did beautify this xml before adding it here).

Comment: Are you able to write a simple .net application to prove whether the output is being received correctly. See the System.Diagnostics.Process type in .net, with output redirection enabled.

Comment: I will try that. How does stderr differ in a C application compared to a C# application? Would they not write to the same stream?

Comment: There should be no difference, the approach allows you to isolate and test the issue. CruiseControl.net uses the process type to capture stderr output.

Comment: Just for completeness, are you able to see output on stdout using `fputs`?

Comment: Yes, and errorlevel is set accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried routing your exe via cmd? Executing `cmd /c your.exe` and see if stderr is emitted via this approach?

Comment: Tried that now. Empty output as before.

Comment: Debugging CruiseControl.NET from source reveals that the output from the command is recognized as standard error output. Check the edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105780/discussion-between-simon-laing-and-anders-linden).